# How to discard changes in AWS lambda function inline editor?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So when I'm in the aws lambda function editor, if I type anything in the inline editor, I get "changes not deployed".

How do I discard my changes so that my text returns to how it was before my typing and the "changes not deployed" disappears? Must be something obvious, but I don't see a way to do it. Even closing the lambda function and reopning has it still there.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code has been **saved** within the editing environment, but the code has not been **deployed** to the production Lambda servers. You could possibly use Undo to revert the text in the editor to a previous version, but that capability would be lost if the page is reloaded. If you want to revert to the currently-deployed version, you might be able to use [get-function — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html): _"Returns information about the function, with a link to download the deployment package that's valid for 10 minutes."_

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have not found a way to do this directly from the editor menu items.

However, if you go to the editor settings (shortcut ctrl-,), and search for the binding for `resetlambdafunction`, you can assign a key sequence that will revert the pending Lambda changes.

Another option I found was to clear all cookies.

Comment: `[CTRL-R]` is the default shortcut to restart Cloud9, which will also clear the local changes.   Ironically, found this by trying to bind `resetlambdafunction` to CTRL-R :)  Also perhaps of note - the documentation indicates a "Revert to Saved" option, but it isn't present in the Lambda environment:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/menu-commands.html

Comment: If you open the Lambda source code in a new incognito tab it works easiest, then you don't have to clear cookies. :)

Comment: Crazy that there's not an easier way to do this. Cheers

Comment: Seems like a weird oversight... Makes you wonder why this is still not a clear button 2 years later.